# I wrote a quick Grep in python to use in my research. It works great but prints a ton of "none"s in the command window when its executed. Why?

Tags: python, function, return, structure

I've been using this little function in a lot of my other scripts to grab important information from text files that my numerical models spit out. It works fine but it fills the command window the "none" when it is executed. Any idea why? I believe it has something to do with the fact the function doesn't return anything?

Here is the code:

```
#Grep for python. To run from command prompt: python -c 'import grepy; grepy.grep("input.txt","keyword",'output.txt)'

def grep(f1,search,f2):
        f2 = open(f2,'w')
        for line in open(f1):
            if search in line:
                print f2.write(line)
        f2.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
        grep()
```

Comment: `f2.write(line)` returns `None` and you're printing it.

Comment: @Vincent that's an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
print f2.write(line)
```

makes no sense; it prints the return value of `write()` which is `None`.

Decide if you want the output to be printed and/or written to a file, and do the right thing(s).

Also your code looks somewhat fictional, since you don't pass the required arguments to `grep()`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the print statement. It was there from when I was debugging the code that was written differently. Forgot to remove it since the code ran fine. Thanks!